# table border radius not match hover background-colour

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCSMo.png)

when i hover the background-colour comes out of the table border radius the corner of table bleed out when i hover coursor on it you can check on it

```css
table, td, th {border: 1px solid;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 15px;
                font-family:'League Gothic', sans-serif;
                font-size:25px;
                colour:green;}
 
  th, td {border-style: groove;
          border-color: #96D4D4;}
 
td:hover {background-color: #5eff67;
          }

table {
        border-collapse:collapse;
        background-color:#77fc7e;
        border-radius: 30px;
        border-style: hidden; /* hide standard table (collapsed) border */
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #666; /* this draws the table border  */ 
    }

   td{  
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
      
        transition: background-color 0.5s
    }
```

```html
<table border="1"  >
 
<tr>
<td><a href=#smile >smile section</a><br></td>
<td><a href=#exercise >physical activity</a><br></td>
<td><a href=#sleep > sleeping habit </a><br></td>
<td><a href=#eating> eating     </a><br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href=#grateful> greatful </a> </td>
<td><a href=#providing> providing   </a> </td>
<td><a href=#breathe>breadth    </a> </td>
<td><a href=#acknowledgement> acknowledgement </a> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `table { overflow: hidden; }` to the CSS

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: 'League Gothic', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  colour: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

th,
td {
  border-style: groove;
  border-color: #96D4D4;
}

td:hover {
  background-color: #5eff67;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #77fc7e;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border-style: hidden;
  /* hide standard table (collapsed) border */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #666;
  /* this draws the table border  */
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  transition: background-color 0.5s
}
```

```html
<table border="1">

  <tr>
    <td><a href=#smile>smile section</a><br></td>
    <td><a href=#exercise>physical activity</a><br></td>
    <td><a href=#sleep> sleeping habit </a><br></td>
    <td><a href=#eating> eating     </a><br></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><a href=#grateful> greatful </a> </td>
    <td><a href=#providing> providing   </a> </td>
    <td><a href=#breathe>breadth    </a> </td>
    <td><a href=#acknowledgement> acknowledgement </a> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```